# In flex, how to associate value to String under Combo Box?

Tags: apache-flex, combobox

How can I give value to combo box entries. For example, in combo box, I have Array Collection and inside it, I am adding strings like mx:String. I want to give it different value than the text. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `labelField` property in the ComboBox to specify the field in your dataProvider which will be seen as the label in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

alternatively, use the [labelFunction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform//reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/ComboBox.html?allClasses=1#labelFunction) to create a label that doesn't necessarily rely on a single field.